# Are there any feats or equipment that can be used to assist a base melee character in ending a Rage?

Tags: dnd-5e, barbarian

To end a Barbarian's Rage, the Barbarian has to neither attack nor take damage for a turn, or be rendered unconscious. What options are available to all characters to ensure the end of an enemy Barbarian's Rage?

Options such as dealing enough damage to reduce the Barbarian's HP to 0 or being on a different continent are obvious but not helpful.

For example, a Champion Fighter has no (base) abilities that might be used for this. Is there any equipment or feats he might be able to employ (without using abilities outside of his own class) to help?

Comment: The question (and it's a good, useful question appropriate for this forum) is really "what specific game mechanics can an adversary use to end Rage?"  I'm a little baffled at the votes to close.  It just needs some clarification.

Comment: @nitsua60 glad to help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A net. A successful hit restrains a large or smaller creature. They can use their action to escape with a strength check or cut their way out but either of those will end the rage as long as nobody has dealt damage to them.

Comment: +1, but it might be worth noting that the Barbarian could just make a ranged attack.

Answer (score 4):

> Are there any other abilities that can be used, other than to KO the user, avoid being attacked by them, and avoid attacking them (dealing damage)?

There are three ways to end rage. The ways you end rage are explicitly detailed  in the PHB

> It ends early if you are **knocked unconscious** or **if your turn ends and you haven’t attacked a creature since your last turn** or **taken damage since then.**

And that is the only way, per the rules.

Mechanically, grapple doesn't work because he can still attack you, and restraining him also doesn't work because that condition still allows him to attack. You can knock someone out by reducing their hit points to 0 as well, and a melee attacker can choose to leave them stabilized and unconscious.

Your only options are not something that is a "move" or ability you can do, you would just have to prevent him from attacking something, which could be as easy as taking the dash action away from him or as complicated as tying him up and taking away his ability to make an attack. Get creative, you can do more than the book says you can do.

Bottom line is, you can't really stop a barbarian from raging. It's what he does. Other classes excel at other things, like getting free hitpoints from turning into a bear, or being able to cast magic, or being really sneaky. The barbarian is good at hitting things and taking a beating. He can only do it so many times per day and taking that away from him is like taking away a class feature. You can probably do it, but it's just not worth it and not that big of a problem.

Comment: It is that big of a problem if I'm facing off against a Raging Barbarian though. I do apologise for the confusion of the original question, and the following multiple edits.  The question I'm trying to ask is are there any feats or equipment that can be used to assist a base melee character (eg a Champion Fighter) in ending a Rage?

Comment: "and restraining him also doesn't work because that condition still allows you to attack." But if you *don't* attack, restraining works fine right?

Comment: I would personally think so, as the goal is to stop the Rage. If I could restrain a Barbarian, then I would want to *not* attack, so that the parameters are met.

Comment: @doppelgreener The barbarian can still attack, so the rage continues. I mean restraining him with the actual "restrained" condition. To completely tie him up, sure, as long as he isnt damaged for 1 turn and he doesnt make an attack.

Comment: @PremierBromanov Gotcha. I've given your post an edit to keep the pronouns for each party consistent for clarity.

Comment: @nitsua60 not as it pertains to the question at hand (feats, equipment)

Answer (score 0):

The only ways to stop a barbarians rage is for him to either attack or take damage (assuming you don't want to have to go through his entire HP supply to knock him out).

So if you're trying to stop him, you'll need spells like Command, Charm Person, etc... to make him stop attacking (note: won't work on a level 6 or higher Berserker, they're immune to charm), or to put him somewhere where he cannot attack with something like banishment, hold person, entangle, etc...

Something like a net *might* work, but that if they try to cut their way out, that *could* count as an attack...  Any sort of grapple will just mean he can't move away from you (but since you have to be right there, he can just attack you).

EDIT: saw your mention of base melee.  not really much you can do.  magical weapons will pierce the barbs resistance, so get yourself one of those to help bring his health down fast enough to knock him out, ending his rage.

Comment: "What options are available to *all characters* to ensure the end of an enemy Barbarian's Rage?"  Spells are not available to all characters.

Comment: Rage requires an attack against a creature to continue so attacking just the net won't allow rage to continue.

Comment: @LegendaryDude yes, spells are not available to all characters, but it is tangentially related to the original post, and I did include a comment about options for non-casters.